# C++ linked list argument of type "Node*" incompitable

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I have the following linked list in c++ program. I think its built properly.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next = NULL;
};
void addNode(Node *head, int data);

int main()
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* next = NULL;
    };

    Node *head = new Node;
    head->data = 3;
    addNode(head, 5);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void addNode(Node *head, int data)
{
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    Node *newnode = new Node;
    curr->next = newnode;   
}
```

First I create a node struct, and then I create a `head` and set it to a `new Node.` I also just set the `head->data = 3`. Then I call my `addNode` function which takes in a `Node * head`, and essentially adds a node to the end of linked list. However when I pass in the head, in the statement `addNode(head, 5)`, I get an error saying `'void addNode(Node *,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'main::Node *' to 'Node *'`

Why is this? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why you define `Node` inside `main()` again? It's irrelevant, has nothing to do with the original one.

Comment: When I initialize the prototype it doesnt know when Node is so I gotta create the struct again

Comment: What do you mean `initialize the prototype`? Which prototype? For the code you showed, just remove the definition inside the `main()` would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a general scope issue. Within your `addNode` function, the `struct Node` being used is the one declared before your `main()`. However, the code inside of your `main` function uses the redefined `struct Node` within the scope of `main`...hence the error saying `cannot convert main::Node* to Node*`.

Remove the definition of `struct Node` from inside of your `main` and it should work.

Also, inside of your `addNode` function, you aren't setting the data value of the new `Node`, so be sure to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next = NULL;
};
```

Your problem is that you're defining a separate type with a different scope.  Your compiler is thinking of the 1st definition as something analogous to `global::Node`, while the 2nd definition is `main::Node`.

So, in reality, when you assign a value to head, you are assigning incompatible types (`global::Node* = main::Node*`), so your compiler is throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks. Also I have a quetsion. Whats the difference between `Node *head = new Node;` and `Node *head = new Node();`? They both seem to work

Comment: The parenthesis call a data type's initialization function, or 'constructor'.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

You should always initialize variables whenever possible.  Doing otherwise can cause undefined behavior.  For a more detailed explanation, check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: I'm going to add on to this comment with an example.

Say you have `struct Foo {int bar;} ;`, and it has an initializer that sets `foo.bar` to `0` when you declare it.  Calling `x = new Foo` will set the value of `x->bar` to something undefined, while calling `x = new Foo()` will set `x->bar` to `0` every time.